# How to add type annotation in let binding

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner(ish) in Haskell and I find error message really hard to understand (I guess it comes with time). Anyway, to help me understanding my mistakes, I tried to add intermediate variable with type annotation in a let binding and found that it generate even more errors, even though my type are (I think) correct.

Example;

```
f :: a -> a
f x = 
    let x' = x :: a
    in x'
```

Generate the following error

```
test.hs:3:12:
Couldn't match expected type `a2' with actual type `a'
  `a2' is a rigid type variable bound by
       an expression type signature: a2 at test.hs:3:12
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for f :: a -> a at test.hs:1:6
In the expression: x :: a
In an equation for x': x' = x :: a
In the expression: let x' = x :: a in x
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to do so ?

Comment: I'm assuming you correctly wrote `f x = ...` rather than `let f x = ...`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Solution

You need the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension for this to work, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall a. a -> a
f x = 
    let x' = x :: a
    in x'
```

#### Explanation

If you have a type signature like this

```
f :: a -> a
```

then it indicates that `f` is polymorphic and works for any choice of `a`. So `f` could be
used at type `Int -> Int`, or at type `Bool -> Bool`, or at type `[Int -> Bool] -> [Int -> Bool]` – whatever you like.

If you have a type annotation like this

```
x :: a
```

it means a similar thing, namely that `x` should be usable at any type of your choice. But that's not true in your case. The outer function `f` is polymorphic, but within the function, `x` has to be of the *same* type `a` that the user has chosen for the outer `x`. By default, Haskell makes no connection between type variables occurring in different type signatures and annotations. However, you can tell it to do so by enabling the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. Now, by prefixing `a -> a` with `forall a.`, you can explicitly instruct Haskell to make `a` visible as a specific type variable within the definition of `f`. If you then annotate `x :: a`, it refers to the outer `a` rather than a new polymorphic `a`.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who is looking to type annotate the binding instead of the expression - `ScopedTypeVariables` allows you to do that too!

```
f1 = do
  let x :: Int = 5
  y :: Int <- someMonadicOperation
  return $ x + y
```

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for that for ages !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
f :: s -> s
f x =
   let y = undefined :: s
   in  y
```

Just use the normal `::` operator as shown in the above example for type annotation.

Update:

It doesn't seem to work with polymorphic types. But it works with an concrete type.

The following typechecks:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = let m = x :: Int
      in m
```

This produces error:

```
f1 :: a -> a
f1 x = let m = x :: a
       in m
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you have not defined the function itself" ? the function is well defined and run if I remove the type annotation

Comment: The third example is basically my question, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work with polymorphic type. Use `ScopedTypeVariables` extensions for that as explained by komiskus.